# How Do I Listen and Capture A JSON Post From Webhook (C#)

Tags: c#, webhooks

So I have only ever interacted directly with the API endpoints of my ERP and parsed the JSON responses from those calls, never created a webhook to listen for a post from them.  There are several event triggers to which I am going to subscribe webhooks.  I have no clue how to properly to create the files that will listen and be ready for the json that my ERP is going to post to me.

I turn to the experts here who have never let me down for assistance.  I'm not looking for an elegant solution, just one that works.

Comment: in the end the webhook to which you subscribe does all the work for you, what you need is just an api endpoint which accepts the model from the webhook, you give the webhook the endpoint and the hook does everything for you. So there is no need for a complicated construct

Comment: @Isparia, yes that is the part I need help with "accepting the post from the webhook" I'm only used to working posts back from the page itself, and not being sent from a third party.

Comment: take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio , when you finished this all you need to do is setup your models and give your erp the endpoints which to call/post

Comment: WebHooks Inro: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks ASP.NET WebHooks receivers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/receivers